# How to find descriptive statistics using groupby in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new with Python so, I think this is just a basic but I can not find it. 
I have this kind of data frame which consist of 100 question

```
|Date|QID|Time_1|Answer_1|Time_2|Answer_2|Time_3|Answer_3|
|1/12|001|20    |  A     |  30  |   A    |  34  |   D    |
|1/12|001|22    |  A     |  10  |   A    |  12  |   D    |
|1/12|002|27    |  B     |  40  |   A    |  45  |   D    |
|1/12|002|25    |  A     |  60  |   C    |  23  |   D    |
```

So, I want the descriptive statistic for a time such as max, min, mean for overall time.

Such in the sample data, this is the output:

**Output**

```
|QID| Mean | Min | Max |
|001| 21.33| 10  |  34 |
|002| 36.67| 23  |  60 |
```

How can I do that?

I have use

```
df.mean(axis=1)
df.max(axis=1)
df.min(axis=1)
```

But how to find the descriptive statistic using group by based on the QID.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Main complication of solution is not exist `mean` of `mean`s, so is necessary create `mean` by definition - it is sum of `sum`s divided by sum of `count`s.

So first get aggregations per rows with [`DataFrame.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html), instead `mean` use `sum` and [`DataFrame.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.size.html) and then aggregate `sum`, `min` and `max`, last divide columns for `mean`:

```
cols = df.filter(like='Time').columns

df1 = df[cols].agg(['sum','size','min','max'], axis=1)
df = df1.groupby(df['QID']).agg(m1=('sum','sum'),
                                m2=('size','sum'),
                                Min=('min','min'),
                                Max=('max','max'))
df = df.assign(Mean=df.pop('m1').div(df.pop('m2'))).reset_index()
print (df)
   QID  Min  Max       Mean
0    1   10   34  21.333333
1    2   23   60  36.666667
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `df.describe()` it yields all of the information you're after. `.describe()` is a DataFrame method so you can stick it at the end of any GroupBy statement that returns a `DataFrame` object.

Here are the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html